# One SQL Stored Procedure to get cut off date of two different cut off date format

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one system that read from two client databases. For the two clients, both of them have different format of cut off date:

1) Client A: Every month at 15th. Example: 15-12-2016.

2) Client B: Every first day of the month. Example: 1-1-2017.

The cut off date are stored in the table as below:
[image]

Now I need a single query to retrieve the current month's cut off date of the client. For instance, today is 15-2-2017, so the expected cut off date for both clients should be as below:

1) Client A: 15-1-2017

2) Client B: 1-2-2017

How can I accomplish this in a single Stored Procedure? For client B, I can always get the first day of the month. But this can't apply to client A since their cut off is last month's date.

Comment: Do you store the *offset* (or *cut off*) somewhere? I'd assume that there is a `Client`'s table with a column `CutOff INT NOT NULL` where B has got `1` and A has got `15`. Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: @Shnugo unfortunately, there isn't anywhere that store those value. We only have the cut off date as it is entered by our clients

Comment: So the oldest (first) existing date for a client determinates this *cut off date*? How far in the future do you need this?

Comment: @Shnugo actually the data had been existed for several years. It's the same cut off date for entire year in future and same for the past. Just that I showed part of the data for better understanding on how their cut off date looks like. It's not the first date that determine cut off date, clients actually key in all 12 month cut off date by their own. It's so happen that their cut off date is that way

Answer (score 0):

Might be something like this you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @DummyClient TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,ClientName VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @DummyDates TABLE(ClientID INT,YourDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @DummyClient VALUES
 ('A'),('B');
INSERT INTO @DummyDates VALUES 
 (1,{d'2016-12-15'}),(2,{d'2017-01-01'});

WITH Numbers AS
(          SELECT 0 AS Nr
 UNION ALL SELECT 1
 UNION ALL SELECT 2
 UNION ALL SELECT 3
 UNION ALL SELECT 4
 UNION ALL SELECT 5
 UNION ALL SELECT 6
 UNION ALL SELECT 7
 UNION ALL SELECT 9
 UNION ALL SELECT 10
 UNION ALL SELECT 11
 UNION ALL SELECT 12
 UNION ALL SELECT 13
 UNION ALL SELECT 14
 UNION ALL SELECT 15
 UNION ALL SELECT 16
 UNION ALL SELECT 17
 UNION ALL SELECT 18
 UNION ALL SELECT 19
 UNION ALL SELECT 20
 UNION ALL SELECT 21
 UNION ALL SELECT 22
 UNION ALL SELECT 23
 UNION ALL SELECT 24
 ) 
,ClientExt AS
(
    SELECT c.*
          ,MIN(d.YourDate) AS MinDate
    FROM @DummyClient AS c
    INNER JOIN @DummyDates AS d ON c.ID=d.ClientID
    GROUP BY c.ID,c.ClientName
)
SELECT ID,ClientName,D
FROM ClientExt
CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,Numbers.Nr,MinDate)
            FROM Numbers) AS RunningDate(D);
```

The result

```
ID  Cl  Date
1   A   2016-12-15
1   A   2017-01-15
1   A   2017-02-15
1   A   2017-03-15
1   A   2017-04-15
1   A   2017-05-15
1   A   2017-06-15
1   A   2017-07-15
1   A   2017-09-15
1   A   2017-10-15
1   A   2017-11-15
1   A   2017-12-15
1   A   2018-01-15
1   A   2018-02-15
1   A   2018-03-15
1   A   2018-04-15
1   A   2018-05-15
1   A   2018-06-15
1   A   2018-07-15
1   A   2018-08-15
1   A   2018-09-15
1   A   2018-10-15
1   A   2018-11-15
1   A   2018-12-15
2   B   2017-01-01
2   B   2017-02-01
2   B   2017-03-01
2   B   2017-04-01
2   B   2017-05-01
2   B   2017-06-01
2   B   2017-07-01
2   B   2017-08-01
2   B   2017-10-01
2   B   2017-11-01
2   B   2017-12-01
2   B   2018-01-01
2   B   2018-02-01
2   B   2018-03-01
2   B   2018-04-01
2   B   2018-05-01
2   B   2018-06-01
2   B   2018-07-01
2   B   2018-08-01
2   B   2018-09-01
2   B   2018-10-01
2   B   2018-11-01
2   B   2018-12-01
2   B   2019-01-01
```